# Draw a de Bruijn graph with random vertex size

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to draw a graph that looks like below,

[image]

This the code I have so far,

```
DeBruijnGraph[4, 2, EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", GraphLayout -> Automatic, 
VertexLabels -> Table[i -> {RandomChoice[{A, C, T, G}], 
RandomChoice[{A, C, T, G}]}, {i, 20}], VertexSize -> 
RandomReal[0, 1],   VertexStyle -> Blue]
```

But I don't get a similiar graph above. Can someone give me a suggestion to graph it? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following changes to your code will produce the desired graph:

1. Change `GraphLayout` to `"SpringElectricalEmbedding"` instead of `Automatic`
2. Instead of using a list of symbols like `{A, C, G, T}`, use strings and concatenate them for the labels.
3. `VertexSize` with a single value uses the same size for all vertices. Instead, use `VertexShapeFunction` with a random disk radius to achieve the same effect.

The resulting code:

```
DeBruijnGraph[4, 2, 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
    GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
    VertexLabels -> Table[i -> Row@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "T", "G"}, 2], {i, 20}], 
    VertexShapeFunction -> ({Opacity@0.5, Blue, Disk[#, RandomReal[{0.05, 0.2}]]}&)
]
```

[image]

---

If you want to get perfect circles for the self-loops, it might be easier to use the older `GraphPlot` instead of the newer `Graph`-style functions.

```
adjMatrix = AdjacencyMatrix@DeBruijnGraph[4, 2];
With[{vertexLabels = Table[i -> Row@RandomChoice[{"A", "C", "T", "G"}, 2], {i, 20}]},
    GraphPlot[adjMatrix,
        SelfLoopStyle -> All,
        Method -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding",
        MultiedgeStyle -> 0.2,
        PlotStyle -> Lighter@Orange,
        VertexRenderingFunction -> Function[{center, label}, 
            With[{radius = RandomReal[{0.05, 0.2}]}, 
                {Opacity@0.5, FaceForm@Blue, EdgeForm@Black, Disk[center, radius], 
                 Black, Text[label /. vertexLabels, center + Min[1.75 radius, 0.25] {Cos[Pi/4], Sin[Pi/4]}]}
            ]
        ],
        VertexLabeling -> True,
        PlotRangePadding -> None
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Can we make the self-loops a perfect circles?

Comment: @Silvia Good catch! I couldn't get it to work with `EdgeShapeFunction` but [I knew it was possible](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3688/5) using the older `GraphPlot`, so I've updated my answer with a perfect-circle self-loop version :)

Comment: Then +1 :) (Totally forgot `GraphPlot`!)

Comment: for a perfect circle loop, set EdgeShapeFunction -> (Line[#] &)..

Comment: @halmir Hmm... It doesn't show up as a perfect loop here :( 10.3 on OS X El Capitan

Comment: @R.M. did you change "Line" to (Line[#]&) ?